# Counting all the nodes in a Linked List

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to write a simple method to count all the nodes in the linked list.  I know there are 7 items in the linked list, but it is returning just 6 of them.

Here is my method

```
public int count() {
    int count = 0;
    for (ListNode n = head; n.next != null; n = n.next) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

And here is my ListNode.java

```
public class ListNode {

String name;        // a name in the list
ListNode next;      // the next node in the list
ListNode prev;      // the previous node in the list

/**
 * Constructor with just a name. This form would be most useful when
 * starting a list.
 */
public ListNode(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    next = null;
    prev = null;
}

/**
 * Constructor with a name and a reference to the previous list node. This
 * form would be most useful when adding to the end of a list.
 */
public ListNode(String name, ListNode node) {
    this.name = name;
    next = null;
    prev = node;
}
}
```

Comment: The case is solved. :D Please choose answer now haha.

Answer (score 3):

The end node will fail `n.next != null` but  it is part the the LinkedList, so you should consider that. It sounds like you simply have an indexing error.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

```
for (ListNode n = head; n != null; n = n.next)
```

n.next !=null was the error.

Comment: That's one way to put it :D

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public int count() {
    int count = 0;
    for (ListNode n = head; n != null; n = n.next) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to loop until n == null.  As it stands, you're stopping one short.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's because you are starting your count from 0, neglecting the first node.

Instead initialize `count=1`;

Answer (score 0):

```
public int count() {
    int count = 0;
    for (ListNode n = head; n != null; n = n.next) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`n.next != null`  Is your problem. Change it to `n!=null`

```
 Example : 

List : 1--> 2 -->3--> 4-->null
Count :  1--> 2-->3-->here n=4 and n.next=null. So, your loop will break and count will be 3 (i.e; the last node will not be counted.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't counting the last node. When you get to the last element to be counted, n.next will be null, and so count is never incremented. You might instead try a loop like the following:

```
ListNode n = head;
for (ListNode n = head; n != null; n = n.next) {
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for null first. If not 0, then set 'counter = 1' before you loop through it.

```
if (_first == null) return 0;
            int count = 1;
            for (ListNode n = _first; n.Next != null; n = n.Next)
            {
                count++;
            }
            return count;
```