# How do I sum specific integer variables in all the nodes of a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I have Customer objects in 2 linked lists, queue and served. Each have variables for size of party. The served queue has a randomly assigned wait time. I need a function to sum and return the number of customers in a queue. I think this means summing the integer indicating party size within each Customer object in the wait list, LinkedList.

I need a function to sum and return total number of customers served. This probably means summing the integer indicating party size within each Customer object in the LinkedList of served Customer objects.

I dont know which of the following links if any fits my situation, ie when to use which. Nevertheless, I tried and failed to successfully implement either.

For loop:
[Counting all the nodes in a Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086128/counting-all-the-nodes-in-a-linked-list)

By iteration and recursion:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-length-of-a-linked-list-iterative-and-recursive/

```
    /*Returns count of nodes in linked list */
     public int count(){
         int count=0;
         for(Customer n = ???; n != null; n = n.next){count++;}
         return count;
     }
```

```
//        /* Returns count of nodes in linked list */
//        public int getLineSize(Customer cust) 
//        { 
//            // Base case 
//            if (cust == null) 
//                return 0; 
//            // Count is this customer plus rest of the list 
//            return 1 + getLineSize(cust.next); 
//        } 
//         
//        /* Wrapper over getLineSize() */
//        public int getCount() 
//        { 
//            return getLineSize(); 
//        }
```

I'm not getting any results because I cannot produce sensible, syntax error free code. A runtime error would be progress.

Comment: Try using a forEach loop.

Comment: Try making the whole issue clear. You're refering to a custom linkedlist implementation that you don't provide any info about.

Comment: I thought I provided a good amount of information.  Maybe it's easier to see what's missing from your perspective. I obviously already have all the info.  Can you help me figure out what additional information about my linked list would help?

Comment: For implementing a first in first out queue, you could use a double end queue, a [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html).  Create `Deque<Party> customersWaiting` where Party is a class representing numCustomers, arrival time, served time and a function to calculate wait time.  Given this, the number of customers waiting is `customerWaiting.stream().mapToInt(party -> party.getNumCustomers()).sum();`.  That's just an example, there are many ways to implement this.

Comment: Ideally the additional information that might make the issue clearer would come in the form of a [mcve].  Providing a good quality example that implements all suggestions in the provided link is sometimes difficult and may take quite a bit of work.  Most new askers seem to either struggle mightily with it, or just ignore a lot of advice from the link.  But, a few get it right and get quality help.

Comment: I couldn't get the code to run at all though. So I didn't have a way to make it reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

The Customer Objects in the LinkedLists have a previously defined `getWait()` and `getParty()` methods to get the values of the randomly assigned wait times and size of Party variables of the object.

The functions have to take linked lists.

You use the getFirst method of the LinkedList class to get the first element in the linkedLists.

You use an accummulator variable to get the sums.

Use `n != null;` and `n = n.next` as the stop condition and iteration in the for loop.

You start at `Customer n = (Customer) ll.getFirst()`. Its just shorter to use n and you need an explicit cast. Maybe because the function doesn't know both your link lists have Customer type elements.

Returns sum of waits in linked list:

```
public int sumWait(LinkedList ll){
         int sumWait = 0;
         for(Customer n = (Customer) ll.getFirst(); n != null; n = n.next){
             sumWait = sumWait + n.getWait();
         }
         return sumWait;
     }
```

Returns sum of parties in linked list

```
     public int sumCust(LinkedList ll){
         int sumCust = 0;
         for(Customer n = (Customer) ll.getFirst(); n != null; n = n.next){
             sumCust = sumCust + n.getParty();
         }
         return sumCust;
     }
```

Comment: doesn't look like an answer .. is it meant to be?

Comment: I thought it was a way to penalize the answer to penalize the question.  No one said the answer is wrong let alone why.  I don't see any syntax errors.  I haven't checked for any runtime errors or errors in the results yet.  Why is the answer wrong?  Should I delete the answer? Despite all the penalties I'm not sure what I'm getting penalized for or how to change my behavior.

Comment: no  - I (mis-)read it as a clarification to your question, my fault ;) Will retract the downvote ..